# Best way to write a polling capable application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to build a basic application which will have 2 separate components which are:
  1. Continually poll an external process and store the results within a DB
  2. Grab the results from the DB and display it in a webpage

I'm looking to do this in .Net so I would normally say to do the first component in a Windows Service and the second in ASP.net with a relational dbms like sql server.

The problem with this is that i want to use webhosting to deploy this and they don't tend to allow Windows Services (unless you pay a fortune).  So is it feasible to do the polling component in a seperate asp.net page, or maybe create a spawning worker thread within a single asp.net page that will do the polling for me?

Any opinions/input appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: Consider co-locating a machine or VPS to get this done if you really need to. Don't let a webhost dictate your design!

Comment: A few years ago I wrote an app using the concept described in the blog post referenced below, where a cache object, upon expiration, does some work then creates a new cache object, to stay alive indefinitely. The one problem I had was that every day at around 2am, my hosting company did something, maybe restart IIS, maybe reboot, I don't know, but it interrupted the cycle, and the app stayed dead until someone actually hit a webpage.  I ended up having to write an app locally to ping the site every X minutes, which killed the whole point of the cache object. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this blogpost dealing with [Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/). Some suggestions, lessons learned, etc in the comments. I think I remember a podcast where the scale of the site has forced a move of this code to a Windows Service. You may/not have the same scaling needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static method set up a polling thread under ASP.NET, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

SO is a treasure trove of information, and the [ASP.Net background task](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) comes from a question that was asked during the beta. SO actually uses something similar to this to award badges.

I have personally used this to do exactly what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Where/What is the external process?

If you have any control over that, could you not place your service there?

ASP is fundamentally designed for requests, not for long running processes, you may get something working, but it will never be as robust as something designed for the job.